# what does this rule in /etc/pam.d/system-auth do?

Tags: linux, pam

I'm learning Linux-PAM these days, and stuck by this rule from `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

`session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid`

What exactly **pam_succeed_if.so** is doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is saying to continue iteration through the rules if the service invoking pam is `crond`.

from [`man 8 pam_succeed_if`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if):

> Available fields are user, uid, gid, shell, home and **service**:
>
> ...
>
> field in item:item:...
>     Field is contained in the list of items separated by colons.

And then what is "service"?

From the [PAM application developer docs](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-interface-by-app-expected.html#adg-pam_set_item):

> PAM_SERVICE
>     The service name (which identifies that PAM stack that the PAM functions will use to authenticate the program).